# How does kinit know where the KDC is?

Tags: kerberos

I have built and installed the MIT kerberos code.

I have also got it working on a single machine (tested with sserver and sclient).  I did this as a test bench in order to develop an app which will use kerberos for authentication.  My question is how does kinit know where to send the kerberos requests?  Is there some setup I need for testing in a multi-machine environment?  Is there a DNS call to make?  How does the DNS entry (if used) get created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that each client host needs to have an /etc/krb5.conf file which tells clients where the KDC is located.  (I am talking Linux/Unix here.)

Thanks.

Comment: Don't make life harder than it is. You can enable DNS lookup for KDC in your `krb5.conf`. No need to name KDCs explicitly. Works like a charm here. This is what Windows does.

Comment: DNS lookup of KDCs requires a properly configured DNS server. See http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.6/krb5-1.6.3/doc/krb5-admin.html#Hostnames-for-KDCs